# Get specific column foreach row in DataTable

Tags: asp.net, datatable, webforms, row

How can I get specific column from each row in DataTable. In this example I want to get top 3 news and I got problem with Image. This code gives allways a image from first row, because I defined dr.Rows[0]["Image"]. How can i change this to get right image for every row?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 3 Title, Content, Date, Autor, Category, Image FROM News", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Attributes.Add("class", "post");

        HtmlGenericControl header = new HtmlGenericControl("h2");
        header.InnerHtml = row["Title"].ToString();
        header.Attributes.Add("class", "naslovPosta");
        panel.Controls.Add(header);

        HtmlGenericControl date = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
        date.InnerHtml = ((DateTime)row["Date"]).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.");
        date.Attributes.Add("class", "datumPosta");
        panel.Controls.Add(date);

        Image img1 = new Image();
        img1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Images/" + dt.Rows[0]["Image"]);
        panel.Controls.Add(img1);

        HtmlGenericControl content = new HtmlGenericControl("pre");
        content.InnerHtml = row["Content"].ToString();
        panel.Controls.Add(content);

        pnlNews.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already enumerate all rows, you find the current row in the `row`-variable, so replace:

```
img1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Images/" + dt.Rows[0]["Image"]);
```

with

```
img1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Images/" + row["Image"]);
```

like you did it already f.e. at `row["Title"].ToString();`